# Issue with Carrierwave_Direct + Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, carrierwave-direct

video_uploader.rb

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
  alias_method :extension_white_list, :extension_whitelist
  def will_include_content_type
    true
  end
  default_content_type  'video/mp4'
  allowed_content_types %w(video/mpeg video/mp4 video/ogg)
end
```

Model.rb

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :videosub, VideoUploader
end
```

Parameters:

```
"videosub"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f87201e28 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170509-4704-1mjrwq.mp4>, @original_filename="168C7704-4337-A870-007B2CB22519.mp4", @content_type="video/mp4
```

Error showing is:

```
Validation failed: Videosub is invalid.
```

And if I replace the code inside VideoUploader as:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWaveDirect::Uploader
  alias_method :extension_white_list, :extension_whitelist
  storage :fog 
end
```

Then the file is being successfully being uploaded to S3. But in my case I need to upload the video in background and directly to S3 bypassing the server on which the app is hosted.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: 
Earlier I was including the gem by defining the github path of the repo. Later on I just eliminated the path. And it worked.